How to pass a variable from MS Access to MS Excel
I am working in MS Access and need to pass a variable from MS Access into an Excel Function using VBA.
I've searched for an hour and can't find the answer to this question.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you
Example:
Public Function sub_1() As Double
'MS Access module

    Dim xlapp As New Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim arg1 as Double
    
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlapp.Visible = True
    Set wkb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsm")
    arg1 = 100
    xlapp.Run func_2(arg1) '????

End Function


Public Function func_2(arg1 as Double) As Double
'MS Excel Module

    Dim ans as Double
    ans = arg1 * 2
    debug.Print ans
    func_2 = ans

End Function


xlapp.Run "func_2",arg1.....  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Run

MsgBox xlapp.Run("'" & wkb.Name & "'!func_2",  arg1)   https://jkp-ads.com/rdb/win/s9/win001.htm#:~:text=Or%20use%20this%20to%20call%20a%20macro/function%20with%20arguments

https://jkp-ads.com/rdb/win/s9/win001.htm#:~:text=Or%20use%20this%20to%20call%20a%20macro/function%20with%20arguments shows how to do this.
Basically:
MsgBox xlapp.Run("'" & wkb.Name & "'!func_2",  arg1)


myFinalCode:
Public Function sub_1()
'MS Access module

    Dim xlapp As New Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim arg1 As Double
    
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlapp.Visible = True
    Set wkb =  xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsm")
    arg1 = 100
    xlapp.Run "func_2", arg1

    'Thank you all very much!    

End Sub


Life or Casualty?

You don't need the return value from the function?
